# How can I view my previously scanned checks in Capital One 360?

Tags: capital-one-360

I found an old check in my drawer from a 2 months ago, and I can't remember whether I cashed it or not.

Over on Personal Finance & Money, [when I asked how to see if a check was deposited](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/81819/53258), they recommended that try to view the images from my previously scanned checks online. However, I haven't been able to find a way of doing this with Capital One.

**Is there a way to view images of my previously scanned checks with Capital One 360?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sign into your account at http://capitalone360.com/

[image]

2. Select the account where your check was deposited

[image: Capital One 360 - Accounts]

3. Find the deposited check in your **Transaction History**.

   - It may help to filter by *Transaction Type: All Deposits*

[image: Capital One 360 - Transaction History]

4. Click any deposit to view an image of the check.

[image: Capital One 360 - View check image]

Comment: The interface may differ, as the site was updated a few weeks ago.

Comment: Does not work. When I click on a deposit, a pop down notice shows "Appears on Statement as Mobile Deposit" . There are no other windows showing the check.

Answer (score 0):

I called Capital One and was told they took that feature down so it can be updated.  They said it will probably will be back around May 4th, 2021.

I asked why they would take it down, just to update it.  The agent said you would not believe the amount of calls we are receiving about this problem.  Unbelievable!

Comment: "Probably back around May 4th". Well did you tell them "probably" doth butter no parsnips? I appreciate your answer, not sure why you were downvoted. I called them too about 2 weeks ago. About a week ago I requested physical copies of the checks in case they didn't get it online in time to do taxes. Absolutely ridiculous time of year to do an "update". Not surprised they are inundated with calls. I can only guess they are having technical issues. I think they need to invest more in software development. #CapitalOneFail